# Beyond Android Chrome's navigator.share, how can I add a functional "share" icon to my website?

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

It's fantastic that newer versions of Chrome for Android allow us to use `navigator.share` to launch the native Android sharer.  Super-simple sharing, and in a format that the user is used to rather than something that's different for every website.

So that's one browser taken care of.  But it only account for about 20% of my traffic.  A whopping 50% comes from iOS. And the rest from other android/windows/mac.

Is there anything similar that can be implemented in other browsers, especially iOS Safari?  Or do we have to "roll our own" and/or use a weighty library?

Some Googling threw up http://webintents.org/share, but as far as I can gleam from caniuse.com it only helps on Android Browser and Firefox for Android. Better than nothing, but the demo on that URL doesn't seem to work in those browsers, so maybe this has been discontinued?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the benefit of time passing, iOS now supports the Web Share API, so that handles ~70% of all mobile traffic.

https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-share